# Cannot resolve symbol image_view in Wear OS project

Tags: android, wear-os

I am getting a "cannot resolve symbol 'image_view'" and cannot figure out why.

Here is my main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <android.support.v7.widget.FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
        app:boxedEdges="all" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/image_view" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.FrameLayout>
</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

and my the beginning part of my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.weartest3;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Asset;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.CapabilityClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.CapabilityInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements DataClient.OnDataChangedListener,
        MessageClient.OnMessageReceivedListener,
        CapabilityClient.OnCapabilityChangedListener {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private static final String IMAGE_KEY = "image";
    private static final String TEXT_KEY = "text";
    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }
```

The line:
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view); is showing image_view in red and that's where the error is.

I notice it does not autofind .text in:
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

but it is not showing in red.

I also had problems with:
app:boxedEdges="all"

until I added:
android.support.v7.widget
in:

Which seems strange to me, but that will be a different post.

Comment: I don't see any `R` import in your code. Also, `app:boxedEdges="all"`  'problem' was fixed when you added the support library is because `android:` is pre-baked while `app:` comes from libraries.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer. I don't see a import statement for R in any of the examples. Additionally the R.id.text is not showing an error, but it is also not showing in the dropdown list after typing R.id.

Comment: I closed the project and opened it again and now it seems to be working.